# How to sort the jComboBox elements in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to sort the `jComboBox` elements list into sorted list.

```
JComboBox box=new JComboBox();
box.addItem("abc");
box.addItem("zzz");
box.addItem("ccc");
add(box);
```

i used many jComboBox Components but it's not working.
How to sort this list into ascending order?

Comment: Simply add them in the correct order. You can first add them to a `List` and use `Collections#sort` to avoid manual sorting

Comment: need to add elements in run time..

Comment: See `MutableComboBoxModel#insertElementAt` in that case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have a look at the [`SortedComboBoxModel`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/squirrel-sql/fw/3.2.0/fw-3.2.0-javadoc.jar!/net/sourceforge/squirrel_sql/fw/gui/SortedComboBoxModel.html).

> This model extends the DefaultComboBoxModel and has two additional
>   pieces of functionality built into it:
>
> - upon creation of the model, the supplied data will be sorted before
> - the data is added to the model when adding new items to the model, the
>     items will be inserted so as to maintain the sort order
>
> The default sort order will be the natural sort order of the items
>   added to the model. However, you can control this by specifying a
>   custom Comparator as a parameter of the constructor.

Here's an example how to use it (taken from [there](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/sorted-combo-box-model/)):

```
String[] items = { "one", "two", "three" };
SortedComboBoxModel<String> model = new SortedComboBoxModel<String>(items);
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(model);
comboBox.addItem("four");
comboBox.addItem("five");
comboBox.setSelectedItem("one");
```

[Source code](http://www.camick.com/java/source/SortedComboBoxModel.java)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the default behavior of `addItem` to suit your needs.

**Runnable Example**

```
public class SortedCombobox {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Overriden JCombobox");
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JComboBox box = new JComboBox(){
                    @Override public void addItem(Object obj){
                        int count = getItemCount();
                        String toAdd = (String) obj;

                        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                            items.add((String)getItemAt(i));
                        }

                        if(items.size() == 0){
                            super.addItem(toAdd);
                            return;
                        }else{
                            if(toAdd.compareTo(items.get(0)) <= 0){
                                insertItemAt(toAdd, 0);
                            }else{
                                int lastIndexOfHigherNum = 0;
                                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                                    if(toAdd.compareTo(items.get(i)) > 0){
                                        lastIndexOfHigherNum = i;
                                    }
                                }
                                insertItemAt(toAdd, lastIndexOfHigherNum+1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                box.addItem("zzz");
                box.addItem("hh");
                box.addItem("aa");
                box.addItem("yy");
                box.addItem("uu");
                box.addItem("bb");
                box.addItem("rr");
                box.addItem("aa");
                box.setSelectedIndex(0);

                frame.getContentPane().add(box);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SortedComboBoxModel link from Alexis C. does not appear to work anymore, although the source link still works.

Nonetheless, I created a SortedComboBoxModel for classes that implement Comparable (based on [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JComboBox/Dynamically_adding_sorted_items_to_a_JComboBox.htm)).

```
public class SortedComboBoxModel<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends DefaultComboBoxModel<E> {

    public SortedComboBoxModel() {
        super();
    }

    public SortedComboBoxModel(E[] items) {
        Arrays.sort(items);
        int size = items.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            super.addElement(items[i]);
        }
        setSelectedItem(items[0]);
    }

    public SortedComboBoxModel(Vector<E> items) {
        Collections.sort(items);
        int size = items.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            super.addElement(items.elementAt(i));
        }
        setSelectedItem(items.elementAt(0));
    }

    @Override
    public void addElement(E element) {
        insertElementAt(element, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertElementAt(E element, int index) {
        int size = getSize();
        for (index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            Comparable c = (Comparable) getElementAt(index);
            if (c.compareTo(element) > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        super.insertElementAt(element, index);
    }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.JComboBox<String> sortedComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    String[] testArray = new String[]{"DDD", "AAA", "CCC", "BBB"};
    sortedComboBox.setModel(new SortedComboBoxModel<>(testArray));

    //print out the sorted contents
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedComboBox.getItemCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + sortedComboBox.getItemAt(i));
    }
}
```