# how to filter content in 2nd combo box according to 1st combo box selection

Tags: java, jframe, jcombobox, netbeans-8, ui-design

[image]

I want to filter the degrees when the user select Undergraduate or Postgraduate. I searched through internet, but I couldn't find a clear answer with a sample code.

```
      private String[] itemsUndergraduate = new String[]{"Computer Science", "Software Engineering"};
    private String[] itemsPostgraduate = new String[]{"BA", "Msc"};
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   UPselect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String[] itemsUndergraduate = new String[]{"Computer Science", "Software Engineering"};
    String[] itemsPostgraduate = new String[]{"BA", "Msc"};
    String s = (String) UPselect.getSelectedItem();
    if (s.equals("Undergraduate Degrees")){
        //Assign the first list to the combobox
        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(itemsUndergraduate);
    }
    else{
        //Assign the second list to the combobox
        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(itemsPostgraduate);
    }
}
```

});

This is my code so far, how can I fix this?

Comment: Just use a listener on the top combo box that does a sort on the list for the second box...... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061314/how-to-sort-the-jcombobox-elements-in-java-swing When asking a question you should also include some code showing what you have tried (Action listener, manual sorting, how you create the combobox, etc).

Comment: can i filter that list elements according to 1st combo selection?

Comment: Yes you can. Use an addActionListener to find out when the first box changes, Then remove everything from the second box and add all the elements to it again but in the correct order. See the two links in my comment above.

Comment: am i doing wrong? can you explain it..i attach the code sample

Comment: Don't use **==**. Use the **String.equals()** method instead, for example: `if(s.equals("Undergraduate Degrees")) {`.

Comment: but still this don't change according to 1st combobox..it keep adding items to 2nd box..how to fix it

Comment: Clear the JComboBox before adding new category items: `jComboBox1.removeAllItems();`.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comments and updated code, yes you are on the right path.

Here is an example. First, we need have two lists that we can use later.

```
String[] itemsUndergraduate = new String[]{"Computer Science", "Software Engineering"};
String[] itemsPostgraduate = new String[]{"BA", "Msc"};
```

Now when the first combo box is selected we can change the contents of the second combo box to match one of the lists:

```
UPselect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = (String) UPselect.getSelectedItem();

        //Added this line to help you debug the code
        System.out.print("Does this bit of code ever happen??");
        System.out.print("Value of selected item is: "+s);

        if (s.equals("Undergraduate Degrees")){
            //Assign the first list to the combobox
            jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(itemsUndergraduate);
        }
        else{
            //Assign the second list to the combobox
            jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(itemsPostgraduate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: As DevilsHnd said, make sure you use `s.equals(` instead of `s ==`

Comment: it is asking for class jComboBox1? :(

Comment: @PasinduSenarath I just copied `jComboBox1` from your code. You would only see this error if `jComboBox1` is not accessible to your method. Modify your existing code and it should work.

Comment: my bad..i didn't import that library. now i fixed it.where should i initialized two list.because now i don't get any errors but 2nd box didn't get updated

Comment: @PasinduSenarath You can store them where ever you want. It just depends on what level of access you want to give them. Maybe just make them as private items in the same class as the action listener.
Also, if the list is not updating, then are you sure that `jComboBox1` is the correct combo box to update?

Comment: yeah that is the correct box.still can't understand what is the problem of this

Comment: @PasinduSenarath Use the solution given by DevilsHnd in the comments above.

Comment: @PasinduSenarath After your most recent edit it looks like your action listener is not being registered correctly. Add this line of code to your actionPerformed method: `System.out.print("Does this bit of code ever happen??");`, and you will see that it never happens. You will need to debug your code and find out why.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to have model and modifying data at model rather than updating UI directly, following is an example for the same using `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dropdown Demo");
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            final String SCIENCE = "Science";
            final String COMMERCE = "Commerce";
            final String SELECT = "Choose";
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Stream"));
            JComboBox<String> streams = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{SELECT,SCIENCE,COMMERCE});
            frame.getContentPane().add(streams);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Subjects"));
            DefaultComboBoxModel<String> subjectsModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[]{SELECT});
            JComboBox<String> subjects = new JComboBox<>(subjectsModel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(subjects);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            final String[] SCIENCE_SUBJECTS = {"Maths","Biology","Physics","Chemistry"};
            final String[] COMMERCE_SUBJECTS = {"Economics","Accounts","Taxation"};
            streams.addActionListener((e)->{
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
                    subjectsModel.removeAllElements();
                    subjectsModel.addElement(SELECT);
                    String[] temp = {};
                    if(SCIENCE.equals(streams.getSelectedItem())){
                        temp = SCIENCE_SUBJECTS;
                    } else if(COMMERCE.equals(streams.getSelectedItem())){
                        temp = COMMERCE_SUBJECTS;
                    }
                    for(String sub : temp){
                        subjectsModel.addElement(sub);
                    }
                    frame.pack();
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

On launch:[image: without selection]

On Change:[image]